# PHP - Login Page

Tags: php, authentication

We both thought it was working but I tested it and it doesnt output anything. It checks if theres sessions e.t.c and if not then its meant to output a form but it doesnt can anyone enlighten me on my error?

Code:

```
<?php

session_start();

//Include Database Config.
include('../cdn/global/db.php');

//PDO Settings.
$opt = array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";

//Create a PDO Session.
$DBH = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $opt);

//Session Attributes.
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$loginForm = "
<form method='POST' action='' class='pure-form' style='color: #000;'>

    <fieldset class='pure-group'>
        <input type='text' name='username' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-input-1-2' placeholder='Username'><br>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class='pure-group'>
        <input type='password' name='password' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-input-1-2' placeholder='Password'><br>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class='pure-group'>
        <button type='submit' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary'>Login</button>'
    </fieldset>

</form>";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    echo $_POST['username'].'is trying to login with password'.$_POST['password'];
    $st = $DBH->prepare("SELECT :username FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
    $st->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password']);
    $st->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);

    $st->execute();

    if($st->rowCount()){    
        $row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row->username;
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
        return true;
    }
} else if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo $loginForm;
}

?>
```

Comment: You're missing `session_start()`. Also, what if users have the same password...? Your `WHERE` clause should look like this - `WHERE username = :username AND password = :password`. (*You forgot to check the username*)

Comment: Thank you, Added the new Query, Where should session_start() go?

Comment: At the very top of every single script that needs to use sessions. So, essentially `<?php session_start();`

Comment: Added it and still no change it seems.

Comment: This line `if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_POST['username'])  && !isset($_POST['password'])) {` is eccessive, you should only check for the `$_SESSION` variable, not the post ones, that's probably causing you grief.

Comment: Still nothing unfortuanetly :/

Comment: I think you should use `if else` not  `else if` because you'll get confused.

Comment: @aldrin27 That wont work either, Just makes the page unable to load says unexpected else expecting )

Comment: Can you `print_r($_SESSION)`?

Comment: Can you edit the page with all the changes you've  made thus far?

Comment: Seems like my DB settings (Username Password etc) wasnt loading when I tried loading from http://.org/login/db.php but ../db.php worked not sure why. Now the form is loading but when I enter in correct username and password nothign seems to happen it just reloads the page.

Comment: I found my issue, the session was being set in login() which could only be executed if there was a session so because there was no session to start with there could never be a session to go execute login() so I swapped the conditions around and now its executing the login() bit. I have modified the code a small bit to remove the function as its pointless. The issue now is that its still not making a session I did echo $_SESSION['username']; and nothing output.

Comment: $row seems to be empty and not seem to get any data why? I confirm that post data is correct and the info is the same as from the DB but it seems that its not grabbing the info and putting it into $row

Comment: You need to change it from `SELECT :username` to `SELECT username` as it's treated as a bind...

Comment: Nothings going into if($st->rowCount()){}  Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Thx darrent the username bit fixed it. My only issue is now the session stays set, How can I add some kind of remember me checkbox and a logout button that removes all sessions?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be resolved if you remove the isset from the first two lines so your first lines should look as follow:

```
if(!$_SESSION['username'] && !    $_POST['username'] && ! $_POST['password']) { 
    echo $loginForm; 
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $grantAccess = login(); //after some serious validation or validate inside  
    if(!$grantAccess) { 
        echo 'Test 2';
    }
}
```

Comment: Completely Wrong, !isset is meant to be there 100%

Comment: Maybe you're right but i usually do it this way and it works always and btw you have to be careful to add at the top of the page <?php session_start() ; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I try to separate tasks so I can keep things straight. Here is basically what I do. Note, all the functions would be on their own files included as needed into any pages that require them. I have notated areas of interest:

```
<?php
session_start();
// This would be better as a static class so as not to create new connections all the time
// You can populate all the false values here with actual database info
// If you do it here, then the function will not need arguments when you go
// To use it. The only time you would populate the args after this point is if
// you need to connect to multiple databases on the same page.
function Connect($host = false,$username = false,$password = false,$dbname = false)
    {
        try {
                //Create a PDO Session.
                $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password,array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ));
                //Session Attributes.
                $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "<code><pre>".print_r($e)."</pre></code>";
                $con    =   false;
            }

        return $con;
    }
// Since you are just assigning a variable some html, may as well make it a bit flexible in a function (just incase)
function LoginForm($settings = false)
    {
        $method =   (!empty($settings['method']))? $settings['method']:"post";
        $action =   (!empty($settings['action']))? $settings['action']:"";
        $id     =   (!empty($settings['id']))? ' id="'.$settings['id'].'"':"";
        $class  =   (!empty($settings['class']))? $settings['class']:"pure-form";

        ob_start();
?>
<form method='<?php echo $method; ?>' action='<?php echo $action; ?>' class='<?php echo $class; ?>' style='color: #000;'<?php echo $id; ?>>

    <fieldset class='pure-group'>
        <input type='text' name='username' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-input-1-2' placeholder='Username'><br>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class='pure-group'>
        <input type='password' name='password' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-input-1-2' placeholder='Password'><br>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class='pure-group'>
        <button type='submit' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary'>Login</button>
    </fieldset>

</form>
<?php
        $data   =   ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean(); 
        return $data;
    }

function fetch($sql = false,$bind = false,$obj = false)
    {
        if(empty($sql))
            return 0;

        $query  =   Connect()->prepare($sql);

        if(!$query)
            return 0;

        $query->execute($bind);

        while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $row[]  =   $result;
            }

        if(!empty($row)) 
            $row    =   ($obj)? (object) $row : $row;
        else
            $row    =   0;

        return $row;
    }

function user_login($username = false, $password = false)
    {
        $st     =   fetch("SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username = :username",array(":username"=>$username));
        $valid  =   false;
        if($st != 0) {
                if($st[0]['password'] == $password) {
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $row[0]['username'];
                        $valid  =   true;
                    }
            }

        return $valid;
    }

function user_logout($location = 'loggedout.php')
    {
        if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'logout') {
                session_destroy();
                header("Location: ".$location);
                exit;
            }
    }

// Include Database Config.
// If you just have $username,$password,$host,$dbname here,
// you can skip this if you just add those values into the Connect()
// function as default arguements
include('../cdn/global/db.php');
//Add static function that listens for logout
user_logout();
// If username set (password is also going to be set)
if(!empty($_POST['username']))
    // Get true/false for user hit
    echo (user_login($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']))? "Welcome ".htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']) : "Invalid username and/or password!";
// If there is no session username, show login form
echo (empty($_SESSION['username']))? LoginForm() : '<a href="?action=logout">Log Out</a>';
?>
```

**EDIT: How I would do it in this scenario (in a general sense)**

*/functions/functions.php*

```
<?php
function Connect($host = false,$username = false,$password = false,$dbname = false)
    {
        try {
                //Create a PDO Session.
                $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password,array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ));
                //Session Attributes.
                $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "<code><pre>".print_r($e)."</pre></code>";
                $con    =   false;
            }

        return $con;
    }
// Since you are just assigning a variable some html, may as well make it a bit flexible in a function (just incase)
function LoginForm($settings = false)
    {
        $method =   (!empty($settings['method']))? $settings['method']:"post";
        $action =   (!empty($settings['action']))? $settings['action']:"";
        $id     =   (!empty($settings['id']))? ' id="'.$settings['id'].'"':"";
        $class  =   (!empty($settings['class']))? $settings['class']:"pure-form";

        ob_start();
?>
<form method='<?php echo $method; ?>' action='<?php echo $action; ?>' class='<?php echo $class; ?>' style='color: #000;'<?php echo $id; ?>>

    <fieldset class='pure-group'>
        <input type='text' name='username' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-input-1-2' placeholder='Username'><br>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class='pure-group'>
        <input type='password' name='password' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-input-1-2' placeholder='Password'><br>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class='pure-group'>
        <button type='submit' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary'>Login</button>
    </fieldset>

</form>
<?php
        $data   =   ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean(); 
        return $data;
    }

function fetch($sql = false,$bind = false,$obj = false)
    {
        if(empty($sql))
            return 0;

        $query  =   Connect()->prepare($sql);

        if(!$query)
            return 0;

        $query->execute($bind);

        while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $row[]  =   $result;
            }

        if(!empty($row)) 
            $row    =   ($obj)? (object) $row : $row;
        else
            $row    =   0;

        return $row;
    }

function user_login($username = false, $password = false)
    {
        $st     =   fetch("SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username = :username",array(":username"=>$username));
        $valid  =   false;
        if($st != 0) {
                if($st[0]['password'] == $password) {
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $row[0]['username'];
                        $valid  =   true;
                    }
            }

        return $valid;
    }

function user_logout($location = 'loggedout.php')
    {
        if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'logout') {
                session_destroy();
                header("Location: ".$location);
                exit;
            }
    }
?>
```

*login.php*

```
session_start();
include_once(__DIR__.'/functions/functions.php');
user_logout();
?><html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['username']))
    echo (user_login($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']))? "Welcome ".htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']) : "Invalid username and/or password!";

echo (empty($_SESSION['username']))? LoginForm() : '<a href="?action=logout">Log Out</a>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: About to try this out. Bit confused on the like location and static functions like logout can you please elaborate on those and how they are working?

Comment: You can run the page as is, it should all work. I am only suggesting to clean up the page that you move all the functions on new pages and include them.

Comment: And depending on what's on this page `include('../cdn/global/db.php');`, you may or may not need it.

Comment: Also, to re-itertate, you do need to populate the arguments in the connect function with db credentials like: `function Connect($host = 'myhost',$username = 'root',$password = 'mypassword',$dbname = 'databasename') { ..etc.`

Comment: When your on about the function Connect() basically thats what I have my db.php setup for. All it has is the info on that. About to start integrating this code and trying it out.

Comment: Yeah, take those database credentials and fill the function with those as defaults. Then you don't need to include that document anymore, just need to include the functions file and call your database anywhere in your page like `$con = Connect();`

Comment: Is the big block of code after EDIT: text the same as the first block of code just withouth start session and a few // notes?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add `session_start()`. The edit is to demonstrate what goes where without all the clutter of comments plus the separation of functions vs view. Let me add the session

Comment: Alright lemme test out this code Gimme a few mins :)

Comment: What do you mean by static class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88622/discussion-between-rasclatt-and-john123).

Comment: By a static class, I really mean a class that uses a static method/variable that assigns your connection like a global. In the Object Oriented Programming world it's called a `singleton`, meaning one instance only. This way every time you call Connect() would be the same resource. In your instance, every time you call the function, it will create a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a class to manager your users. Let's create `db.php` class.

```
<?php

class Db {

private static $_dbase = 'data';
private static $_username = 'root';
private static $_passwd = '';
private static $_host = 'localhost';
private static $_options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
private static $_dsn;
private static $_db;

function __construct() {

}

public static function getDB() {
    if (!isset(self::$_db)) {
        try {
            self::$_dsn = 'mysql:host=' . self::$_host . ';dbname=' . self::$_dbase;
            self::$_db = new PDO(self::$_dsn, self::$_username, self::$_passwd, self::$_options);
        } catch (PDOException $exc) {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
        }
    }
    return self::$_db;
  }
```

}

And now let's create `User.php` class

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once 'db.php';
 class USER {

private $db;

function __construct() {
    $this->db = Db::getDb();
}

public function register($uname, $umail, $upass) {
    try {
        $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        //create the activasion code
        $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass,active) 
                                                   VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass,:active)");

        $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
        $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);
        $stmt->bindparam(":active", $activation);
        $stmt->execute();
        $id = $this->db->lastInsertId('memberID');
        $this->sendMail($id, $activation);
        $this->redirect('sign-up.php?joined');
        return $stmt;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function login($uname, $umail, $upass) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = :uname AND `user_email` = :umail LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname' => $uname, ':umail' => $umail));
        $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            //verifying user.
            if (password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']) && $userRow['active'] === 'Yes') {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

private function sendMail($email,$id, $activation) {
    //send email to the user for account activation.
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Registration Confirmation";
    $body = "Thank you for registering at demo site.\n\n To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n " . DIR . "activate.php?x=$id&y=$activation\n\n Regards Site Admin \n\n";
    $additionalheaders = "From: <" . SITEEMAIL . ">\r\n";
    $additionalheaders .= "Reply-To: " . SITEEMAIL . "";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $additionalheaders);
}
//check if the user is logged in
public function is_loggedin() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) {
        return true;
    }
}
// redirect the user.
public function redirect($url) {
    header("Location: $url");
}
//user log out
public function logout() {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
    return true;
}

//display login form
public function display_login_form() {
    return "
     <form method='POST' action='' class='pure-form' style='color: #000;'>

<fieldset class='pure-group'>
    <input type='text' name='username' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-input-1-2' placeholder='Username'><br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class='pure-group'>
    <input type='password' name='password' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-input-1-2' placeholder='Password'><br>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class='pure-group'>
    <button type='submit' style='display: inline-block;' class='pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary'>Login</button>'
</fieldset>

  </form>";
   }

}
```

We are going to check if the user is logged in and if not display the login form.

```
<?php 
   require_once 'User.php';
   $User = new User();
   $form = '';
   if($User->is_loggedin()){
      $User->redirect('private.php');
   }else{
     $form = $User->display_login_form();
   }
  ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
   <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div><?php echo $form; ?></div>
</body>
```